# ErrorSummary('Cannot hit test a render box with no size.'),

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a money tracker App, in the Column, I have added Container and ValueListenableBuilder When I want to add some notes in my app I see the error which says [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/om2UO.png) And here is my code: [Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oYlx.png) [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCK1K.png) [Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yUVE.png)

Comment: share code with question instead of images.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your ValueListenableBuilder in an Expanded widget and maybe a LayoutBuilder to fix a specific height to your component.

```
Expanded(child :
  LayoutBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) =>
    ValueListenableBuilder()
  )
)
```